# Asynchronous function - error status 0

Tags: java, gwt

I execute my async function and before the result I reload the browser I get error - OnFailure(Throwable) is executed. Status error code is 0.

This problem is on FireFox and Chrome.

Could you tell me what this status code means.

```
do(new AsyncCallback<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Boolean result) {}

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable throw) {
        do_sth();
    }
});

Boolean do() { while(true); }
```

That also return status error 0

Comment: Can you post your code that is giving the problem. It will be easy for us to answer your question

Comment: All me async function have that behaviour. I send some information via sockets. My functions are working, but I have error 0 only when I reload browser before get answer.

Comment: It is not clear why you are reloading the browser before you get the result.

Comment: Because my users can do it and I don't want to crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `0` status code here means the request has been aborted (it could also denote a network error, or the request timed out).

See http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-status-attribute and http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#error-flag

Answer (score 0):

You could always define your `onFailure()` like this (adapted from the [GWT API](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/AsyncCallback.html)) to be able to handle different kinds of failure nicely:

```
public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
  try {
    throw caught;
  } catch (IncompatibleRemoteServiceException e) {
    // this client is not compatible with the server; cleanup and refresh the 
    // browser
  } catch (InvocationException e) {
    // the call didn't complete cleanly
  } catch (YourOwnException e) {
    // take appropriate action
  } catch (Throwable e) {
    // last resort -- a very unexpected exception
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you really still using GWT 1.5 or is it just a mistake when doing the link to the javadocs? We're in 2.5 now (almost), and 2.0 was released 3 years ago already!

Comment: @ThomasBroyer: Just an unfortunate link choice on my part. The page is the same in 1.5 through 2.5 though. Updated the link.